# Is there any benefit of using takeWhile instead of findAll or vice-versa in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Is there any benefit of using takeWhile instead of findAll or vice-versa? As both output the same results. What is the exact difference between takeWhile and findAll.

For example :

```
List age = [1,2,5,7,4,9,93,13]
```

**Using TakeWhile :**

```
age.takeWhile{it>9}
```

It will give output : [93,13]

**Using findAll**

```
age.findAll{it>9}
```

It will give output : [93,13]

Comment: `age.takeWhile{it>9}` should not return any output here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

takeWhile works until it finds first element violating the given condition.
But findAll runs on complete list and returns all elements matching the condition.

Taking an example, we have a list:

```
List age = [1,2,5,17,4,9,93,13]
```

If we run takeWhile on it with below condition:

```
age.takeWhile{it<9}
```

It will output:

```
[1, 2, 5]
```

although 4 < 9, but at index 3, it encountered 17, causing the loop to break here.

But if you run findAll on it:

```
age.findAll{it<9}
```

it will return all elements less than 9 in the list: `[1, 2, 5, 4]`